# Statement seems to have no effect, using __getitem__ method

Tags: python, class

Well, I'm a newcomer in classes world,
I'm reading a python tutorial in order to understand how it works.
and I found this:

```
class GetTest(object):             
    def __init__(self):            
        self.info = {              
            'name': 'Mauro',       
            'country': 'Argentina',
            'number': 12345812     
        }                          

    def __getitem__(self, i):      
        return self.info[i]        


foo = GetTest()
```

foo['country']   # <- Highlighted statement (Statement seems to have no effect)

There's no error, it just doesn't do anything.
I think it suppose to give as output 'Argentina'.

Answer (score 1):

Your final statement is wasted in your code. Unless you’re in an interpreter shell, you need to call `print`:

```
print(foo['country'])
```